# NDKr12 LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file.a in path ../arm64-v8a/file.a

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, arm64, ndk-build

my game is using cocos2dx 2.2.6 I have upgrade the NDK to the the NDKr12 beta1 and try to build my project then I get so many errors at the NdkModule folder and NDK complain that it doesn't found the output file in Ndk Module Path:
cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/lib*/libs/arm64-v8a/file.a
[image: as shown at the image]
what it that mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Add RELEASE.txt to your ndk folder. If that doesnt work you may need to use older versions of ndk.

Comment: @Striker what should RELEASE.txt contain?

Comment: Just put your version like r12c (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve it by specific the target architectures at application.mk
by adding this line:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

Comment: you added this in your ndk?

Comment: It worked for me too, but if I want to deploy my game to arm64-8a architecture or something other than what's specified in APP_ABI can I still do that?

Comment: @MosheRabaev I have added it to Application.mk at proj.android/jni/Application.mk
I didn't test this case

Comment: Yup did that to, thanx!